# Proof of kinetic energy equation

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, gas-laws

Is there a way to prove that $\frac{1}{2} mv^2 $$= \frac{3}{2}RT$
The first one is kinetic energy and the second is the average kinetic energy.
Can this be proved by component of velocity.

Comment: The proof is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory#Properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45838/how-to-deduce-e-3-2kt

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/HBASE/kinetic/molke.html#c1

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory#Properties

These contain proof at various level . Choose according to your mathematical level

Comment: Would you be willing to summarize the proof in case the links break? Additionally, none of these links do a good job of explaining the steps.